# How do I loop through an array in an array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, object, reactjs

I know how to run loops inside react but how do I do it inside an object which is already inside an array being looped?

I am trying to display each ingredient item as an `<li>`, so far I have got it working with recipe but I am lost with ingredient. If anyone could chime in, I'd appreciate it.

```
var Recipes = React.createClass({
// hook up data model
  getInitialState: function() {
    return {
      recipeList: [
        {recipe: 'Cookies', ingredients: ['Flour ', 'Chocolate']},
        {recipe: 'Cake', ingredients: ['Flour ', 'Sprinkles']},
        {recipe: 'Onion Pie', ingredients: ['Onion ', 'Pie-Crust']}
      ]
    }
  },

  loop: function() {
    {this.state.recipeList.flatMap('ingredients').map(item, index) => (
      <li key={index} className="list-group-item">{ingredient.ingredients}</li>
    )}
  },

  render: function() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.state.recipeList.map((item, index) => (
          <div className="panel panel-default">
            <div className="panel-heading"><h3 className="panel-title">{item.recipe}</h3></div>
            <div className="panel-body">
              <ul className="list-group">
              {this.loop}
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
          )
        )}
      </div>
    );
  }
});
```

Comment: just keep nesting your `.map` calls

Answer (score 3):

How about this way :

```
  loop: function(ingredients) {
   return ingredients.map((ingredient, index) => {
    return (<li key={index} className="list-group-item">{ingredient}</li>)
   })
  },

  render(){
      ...
        {this.loop(item.ingredients)}
      ...
  }
```

One more thing, you shouldn't use index of array as `key` because it will be difficult to manage when editting the array later. It will be better if you assign `key` with something very unique like `id` or `index + Date.now()`

Comment: I like the logic here and it makes sense, but I get this console error    

  Uncaught SyntaxError: embedded: Unexpected token (23:48)
  21 | 
  22 |     loop: function(ingredients) {
> 23 |       return ingredients.map(ingredient, index) => (
     |                                                 ^
  24 |         <li key={index} className="list-group-item">{ingredient}</li>
  25 |       )
  26 |     },

Comment: Sorry ! I forget returning value inside the map method. I fixed it.

Comment: Thanks so much, your solution is great! I can't believe it was so simple!

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be missing a `return` statement in the `loop` method.

You can cascade rendering as deep as you'd wish, only remember that you need to call the method instead of just placing it in the component structure (see `this.loop` without call parentheses in your sample):

```
var myComponent = React.createClass({
  renderListElements: function (parent) {
    return this.state.listElements[parent].map((element, index) => (
      <li 
        className="my-component__sub-component__list-element" 
        key={`${parent.uid}_${element.uid}`}
      >
        {element.name}
      </li>
    ));
  },

  render: function () {
    var parentsId = [ 0, 1, 2, 3 ];

    return (
      <div className="my-component">
        {parentsId.map((item, index) => (
          <div 
            className="my-component__sub-component" 
            key={item.uid}
          >
            {this.renderListElements(item)}
          </div>
        )}
      <div/>
    );
  }
});
```